# Grails, Handling session time out in AJAX-call

Tags: ajax, grails, spring-security, session-timeout

I have a Spring-Security based grails-app that I want to redirect to the start page when session times out.

That seems hard to solve so at least I want a solution that redirects to the start page when you click on a link that is connected to an Ajax-function.
That because it's annoying when you click on the link and nothing happens because your session has timed out.
Hope someone can show me a simple solution or at least a solution.

Comment: I think if your ajax is calling an controller action after sesson expiry which has an security annotation spring-security-core plugin automatically redirects user to login page..
If you are using spring-security-rest plugin then you can check the 401 (UnAuthorized) response status and redirect to login page.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to pass the header "nopage" with value "true" with your ajax call, and spring security plugin's `AjaxAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint` will return the http status code 401

Another option is to create a custom authentication entry point. And in `commence` check if its an ajax request, thn just return the `SC_UNAUTHORIZED` response code. In your javascript check if the status code is `SC_UNAUTHORIZED` 401, thn handle it appropriately.

```
class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint extends LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    public CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint(String loginFormUrl) {
        super(loginFormUrl)
    }

    @Override
    void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, javax.servlet.ServletException {
        if (SpringSecurityUtils.isAjax(request)) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED)
            return
        }
        super.commence(request, response, authException)
    }

}
```

Register the bean as spring bean with name `authenticationEntryPoint` (See SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin and find bean with name authenticationEntryPoint, you need to override that bean.

If you are using jquery i think you can use the global [ajaxError callback](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxerror/)